# GWT - getThreadLocalResponse() returns null

Tags: java, spring, gwt, cookies, gwt-rpc

In my web application I am trying to set a cookie with session id on the gwt-rpc servlet side. The servlet is injected using spring(gwt-sl). In order to set the cookie I need the `HttpServletResponse` object, however the `getThreadLocalResponse()` method returns `null`. Declaring my servlet in web.xml fix this problem, unfortunately this is not an option...
Any idea how to fix or bypass the problem? Thanks!

Comment: Well, then go ahead and post it as an answer. That would be more prominent for others to see.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I found the answer. I found a class `org.gwtwidgets.server.spring.ServletUtils`which has `getResponse()` and `getRequest()` methods that work like a charm.